# $http requests get caught in infinite loop while updating angular-ui-sortable list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-ui

I have a MEAN app I'm working on. I'm using [angular ui sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) to manage a list.

I'd like to persist the list's order when the page is refreshed. The following function submits an `$http.post` request for each `present` object in the array.

**It works fine if I trigger it using a button. But I'd like it to trigger every time the user updates the order of the list.**

```
$scope.sortPresents = function() {
    for (var j=0; j < $scope.presents.length; j++) {
        $scope.presentClientToDB(j);
    }
};

$scope.presentClientToDB = function(a) {

    var tmpId = $scope.presents[a]._id;

    $http.post('/api/presents/' + tmpId, {
        title: $scope.presents[a].title,
        notes: $scope.presents[a].notes,
        link: $scope.presents[a].link,
        index: $scope.presents[a].index
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log('great success posting data!');
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('error: ' + data);
    });
};
```

In my `view`, I call this `sortPresents()` function upon updating the list:

```
<ul ui-sortable="{update: sortPresents()}" ng-model="presents" class="list-group">
    ...
</ul>
```

Which freezes my app and causes a repeating torrent of `POST` requests in my terminal (on the Express end, using [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan)).

I understand that ui-sortable's `update` function gets called repeatedly as I click and drag a list item. So I tried placing the function as the `stop` method, to no avail.

Any thoughts on how to fix or better implement this?

Comment: What are you try ing to do?  what does posting to /api/presents/ have to do with sorting the list and why do you do it for every item in the list?  Are you updating each present with a separate api call any time anything changes?

Comment: When an item is moved in the list, its `index` changes, along with the indices of all subsequent items in the list. I need to update the `index` property of the affected `present`s. And actually, I am not sorting anything, so this is a poorly named function. Each present in the list has a corresponding model on the server side that gets updated with a unique API call.

Comment: `Sort` event is called repeatedly. `Update` and `Stop` are called once.

Comment: Off-topic, but the design of http request per changed item is terrible. You should send a single http request will an array of updated items (and ideally, only IDs, instead of updating the entire object)

Comment: Not the least reason of which is that you could easily have the situation where you have item A at index 1 and B at index 2.  Moving B to index 1 should move A to index 2, but you could easily get into the position where one of those ajax calls succeeds and the other fails, leaving two items with the same index.  As @NewDev said, a simple array of the item ids in order would be the lowest overhead way to do it, or just posting the entire list of presents would be fine for a small set (although it sounds like it will be happening a lot).

Comment: If you need real-time communication, like if you are organizing a list of presents where multiple people could be editing the list at once, would be to create a service using something like [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/).  If not then you might just want to do the update after a `$timeout` or something and update the entire list at once.

Answer (score 0):

In your ui-sortable options, you need to set the function variable - not invoke the function. So change to `ui-sortable="{stop: sortPresents}"` (without the parenthesis):

```
<ul ui-sortable="{stop: sortPresents}" ng-model="presents" class="list-group">
    ...
</ul>
```